# Query return date and multiple value based on condition

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this table.
[image]

And when I write the following query, it return all date, feeling, and count.

```
SELECT DATE, Feeling, COUNT(Feeling)
From Table
GROUP BY DATE
```

This is the ouput I got.
[image]
Note: the images I uploaded are from spreadsheet pivot table.

This is my expected output.
[image]

Comment: Repost all your image as text.

Answer (score 0):

You Need to Group by Both the Columns  `DATE` and `Feeling`

```
SELECT DATE, Feeling, COUNT(Feeling)
From Table
GROUP BY DATE, Feeling
```

As per you comment you can covert datetime to date using date function.

```
SELECT date(DATE), Feeling, COUNT(Feeling)
From Table
GROUP BY date(DATE), Feeling
```

Comment: One thing I forgot to mentioned is that the date contain timestamp. That's why group by date, feeling is not working as the way I expected. Do you know if there's a way to exclude the timestamp in query so it can be group by date and feeling.

Comment: @JohnLee you can use `Date(DATE)`